# composing machines in a cycle

Tags: haskell, state-machine

I am working with the [machines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.7.2) library and I have three `Process`es

```
foo :: Process a b

bar :: Process b a

baz :: Process b c
```

I would like to compose them such that both `bar` and `baz` use the output of `foo` as input. Moreover, and this is the part I'm struggling with, I would like to fed the output of `bar` back into `foo`, forming a cycle. Any hints on how to do it?

Comment: maybe you can add what you tried so far

Comment: @Carsten the api of the library does not seem to expose any function to do what I'd like. That's why I'm a bit lost. I'm looking also at the pipes docs looking for some inspiration

Comment: Even if it's possible, I don't think it's safe in general. Simplify away the loop and the splitting off to just asking: if we have `quibble :: Process a a`, can we feed the output of `quibble` back into itself? And then I think we are pretty much immediately in trouble: suppose `quibble`'s very first `Step` is to `Await`...

Comment: @DanielWagner not sure I get your point 100%. quibble could receive input also from somewhere else, not only from itself

Answer (score 3):

First you can use `~>` to compose processes sequentially (`Process x y -> Process y z -> Process x z`), so the problem reduces to interpreting `Process a a`, which you can do with a recursive function carrying a buffer. The buffer gets extended by `Yield` and consumed by `Await`. There is some arbitrariness in how you want to handle `Await` on an empty buffer; here I just take the "no input" continuation and resume normally.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.Machine
import Data.Machine.Process

loop :: Monad m => ProcessT m a a -> m ()
loop p = go [] p where
  go :: Monad m => [a] -> ProcessT m a a -> m ()
  go buffer p = runMachineT p >>= \s -> case s of
    Stop -> pure ()
    Yield o p -> go (buffer ++ [o]) p
    Await p1 Refl p0 ->
      case buffer of
        [] -> go [] p0
        i : buffer' -> go buffer' (p1 i)

loop3 :: Monad m => ProcessT m a b -> ProcessT m b c -> ProcessT m c a -> m ()
loop3 x y z = loop (x ~> y ~> z)

example :: ProcessT IO String String
example =
  encased (Yield "world" (
  encased (Await (\name ->
  MachineT (putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!") >> pure Stop)) Refl (error "No input"))))

main :: IO ()
main = loop example
```